# kibana histogram value field use string?

Tags: kibana

i have a task..
   the Values field of the Histogram must be contain a numeric value

but..  my value field come from string ,like this

```
 traceMsg: api_name=xxx&pageSize=20
```

and i need the 20 as  value field..

```
  {
  "_index": "tracelog",
  "_type": "tracelog",
  "_id": "TS7s-gkUSsiH7gqnkHOjpA",
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {
    "id": null,
    "host": "10.153.192.105",
    "appId": "32",
    "spanIndex": 1,
    "spanLevel": 1,
    "spanFlag": 0,
    "spanId": "1",
    "parentSpanId": "0",
    "taobaoId": 1659018141,
    "traceId": "e7e2e60a6ade4f4ab23df4994b2392ae",
    "traceLoc": "http",
    "traceType": 0,
    "traceUrl": "/trade/search",
    "traceMsg": "api_name=trade_search&queryId=1&sys=true&timeType=created&field=created&order=asc&pageNo=1&pageSize=20",
    "payTime": 1173,
    "logTime": "2014-11-13T16:16:43+0800"
  },
  "sort": [
    1415866603000
  ]
}
```

i don't know how to do.     :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what logstash is for.  Check out the [grok filter](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/filters/grok), which would let you parse the traceMsg field and make your own field for the pageSize value.

Comment: the log service is common for company, and no power to do it ,  I think that's probably a bad idea using kibana do this.  :(

Comment: If you can't make the fields somewhere in your process, then you're hosed.  A common log service (e.g. syslog) could still be fed/forked to ELK for processing in a more advanced way.  It's a fight worth fighting.

Answer (score 0):

How do you insert data on elasticsearch without using logstash? You can use the mutate filter to change the field type.

Comment: You can use [Filebeat](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filebeat-getting-started.html)
 or in Kibana via the `Machine Learning` section you can upload a file. The letter worked for me with CSV files.